# How to show a variable in the navigation bar?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to show the number of equivalent glasses/shots in the navigation bar. For example, WhiskeyViewController's title would update to say "Whiskey (12 shots)".

So I added this method in the slider (IBAction)

```
self.navigationItem.prompt = @"Whiskey (X shots)"
```

There are two variables here Whiskey and the number of shots or glasses of wine.

[image]

How do I go about doing this .prompt doesn't let me format a string.

Comment: Why can't you set the title of the view controller instead?

Comment: @GurtejSingh because the instructions were asking to update the sliderValueDidChange method and implement a function that will let me do what I mentioned above

Comment: Simply use `NSString stringWithFormat`.

Comment: If your ViewController is a part of NavigationController stack then in ViewDidLoad method of ViewController write :    self.title = @"title";

Comment: @rmaddy I tried using NSString stringWithFormat but was not successful I get errors. How would you use NSString with navigationItem?

Comment: Update your question with what you tried.